# How to split this array into three's and place it in <td> using php?

Tags: php, arrays, split

I have an php array of ten numbers

```
$arr = array("first" => "1", "second" =>"2", "Third" =>"3", "Fourth" =>"4",
"fifth" =>"5",, "sixth" =>"6", "seventh" =>"7", "eighth" =>"8", 
"ninth" =>"9","tenth"="10");
```

I have to place these values in a `<td>` by spliting the array in numbers of three 
such that my td contains 
first td contains `<td>`the first three values of an aray`</td>`
second td contains `<td>`the next three values of an aray`</td>`
third td contains `<td>`the next three values of an aray`</td>`
if the remaining values in less than three in number  it must be in the another td
say now i have tenth value so 
my last td must contain tenth value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do the trick.

```
    <?php


$array = array("first" => "1", "second" =>"2", "Third" =>"3", "Fourth" =>"4",
"fifth" =>"5", "sixth" =>"6", "seventh" =>"7", "eighth" =>"8", 
"ninth" =>"9","tenth"=>"10");



array_to_td($array, 3);

//$number is the number of elements in a <td></td>.

function array_to_td($array, $number){

 $count = 0;

 foreach($array as $key => $value){
  if ($count == 0){
   print "<td>";  
  }

  $count++;

  print $value;

  if($count == $number ){
   print "</td>";
   $count = 0;
  }


  }
  if ($count != 0){
   print "</td>"; 
  }  

 }
```

You can do any other operations on the given array as it will remain unchanged.

Comment: ya it will do but look at the answer from gnarf it is simpler
But thanks for your effort

Answer (score 7):

You may use [array_chunk](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.array-chunk.php).

```
foreach(array_chunk($arr,3) as $row)
{
    echo "<td>"; 
    echo implode(" ",$row);
    echo "</td>"; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

PHP's function [`array_splice`](https://www.php.net/array_splice) was pretty much made for this job:

```
$arr = range(1,10);
while (count($arr)) {
  $three = array_splice($arr,0,3);
  echo "<td>";
  echo implode(" ",$three);
  echo "</td>";
}
```

Output:

```
<td>1 2 3</td><td>4 5 6</td><td>7 8 9</td><td>10</td>
```

---

`array_splice($arr,0,3)` removes the first 3 elements from `$arr` and returns them into `$three`

Answer (score 1):

Don't know of there is a function which will split the array like that.. Perhaps do it in a for ?

```
$cnt = count($arr);
for($point = 0; $point < $cnt; $point += 3)
{
    echo("<td>".$arr[$point]." ".$arr[$point+1]." ".$arr[$point + 2]."</td>");
}
```

EDIT:
Of course, inside you should check if there are values left. This assumes the length of the array is a multiple of 3 (which, as you stated, might not be the case)

Answer (score 1):

See this another example

```
<?php
$arr = array("first" => "1","second" => "2","Third" => "3","Fourth" => "4","fifth" => "5","sixth" => "6","seventh" => "7","eighth" => "8","ninth" => "9","tenth" => "10");
echo "<br>";
print_r($arr);
echo "<br>";

?>

<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tr>
<td>
<?php
$i=1;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    echo $value." ";
    if($i%3==0) echo "</td><td>";
    $i++;
}
?>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```